# MDX for Last 2 Members in Fact, not from Dim

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I'm trying to write an mdx that will give me the last 2 Products sold in my Fact table, but instead of that, I always get the latest 2 Products in my Dim table sold. I've googled it, but cannot get the right mdx, so I can retrieve the last records in my fact. So far I have:

```
WITH MEMBER [last] as
FILTER([DIM_PRODUCT].[PRODUCT_ID].[PRODUCT_ID].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Row Count]).item(
FILTER([DIM_PRODUCT].[PRODUCT_ID].[PRODUCT_ID].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Row Count]).count-1).name
MEMBER [previous] as
FILTER([DIM_PRODUCT].[PRODUCT_ID].[PRODUCT_ID].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Row Count]).item(
FILTER([DIM_PRODUCT].[PRODUCT_ID].[PRODUCT_ID].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Row Count]).count-2).name

SELECT {[last],[previous]} on COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
where [DIM_WAREHOUSE].[WAREHOUSE_ID].&[2]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "last two products sold"? The products involved in the last sales? If so, how should the behavior be if there was one sale with more than two products? How do your date and time look like?

Comment: Each sale is recorded in detail in my Fact table - for each product there will be a separate row. Simply, I just want a Calculation, that shows me the last two rows of my fact data.

Comment: Is there any way one can determine **from the data** which records are the last ones? Order of insertion is nothing that SQL or MDX support.